# Elements of Ellipse

Tags: geometry

Given: $3x^{2}+16y^{2}=12$.

Finding the Elements of an Ellipse.

**My solution:**

$$\frac{x^2}{2^{2}}+ \frac{y^{2}}{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^{2}}=1$$

Therefore:

1. Semi-major and semi-minor axes: $a=2$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
2. Foci of an ellipse: $(\pm c; 0)$? $(-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}; 0)$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}; 0)$.
3. Eccentricity: $b^2=a^2-c^2$; $c=\sqrt{4-\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$; $e=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}$.
4. Directrix: $x=\pm\frac{a}{e}=\pm\frac{2}{\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}}=\pm\frac{8}{\sqrt{13}}$.

Please, tell me, whether is my solution right?

Comment: I think you've made a small mistake on number **4.** It should be $\pm \frac{8}{\sqrt{13}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is perfectly right.

Only thing to make it more understandable is find the value of c in part 2.

Comment: You're right, it's my fault.